# left to right transition in view based application on moving from one view controller to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
MyView *view=[[[MyView alloc] init] autorelease];
[view setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
```

I have used flip transition on moving from one view controller to another.but my requirement is from left to right transition. Please help me to way out this problem thanks in advance.
here is my code:

Comment: You can't do it with standart modalTransition. Use UINavigationControllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add QuartzCore Framework and then import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
MyView *next = [[MyView alloc] init];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[self presentModalViewController:next animated:NO];
[animation setDuration:0.40];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
//[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
[[next.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
[next release];
```

Comment: Hi Hector, your code is working fine but it fulfill my half requirement.my requirement is that new view is coming from left and current view  move from right.if you can do so then please help me looking towards you.

Comment: @AlokSrivastava i can't get you. Please explain in detail

Comment: Hector i Used this code for going back. [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; now i want transition style should be right to left. As you answered me. please keep in mind my project is view based application. please tell me i waiting for your response

Comment: @AlokSrivastava Are you sure you aren't looking to UINavigationController? These transitions are one of its native behaviors.

Comment: @MDT yes i am not looking for UINavigationController because i have almost completed my project only this transition style is rest.

Comment: @AlokSrivastava for Right to Left use : 
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];

Comment: @Hector You are right but now this right to left transition is required for this line of code  [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; when this function is called then the transition style should be right to left.hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @AlokSrivastava sorry No idea about that.i will try if i get then i will post it here

Comment: @AlokSrivastava did you get solution ?

Comment: @Hector:ya  your code which helped me for left to right transition but when i am pressing back button then it dose not show right to left transition.while i am using self.parentviewcotroller didmisswithanimation

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are dismissing a view controller 2 from view controller 1. In view controller 2 you are using this

```
[self  dismissModalViewControlleAnimated: NO];
```

Now In the 1st view controller, import of "QuartzCore" header and add viewWillAppear method with code

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    
    [animation setDuration:0.50];
    [animation setTimingFunction:
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a `UINavigationController` and push the `UIViewController` instead of presenting it modally?

Edit:

To change your view-based app into a `UINavigationController` just add this to your AppDelegate

```
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nvcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:nvcontrol.view];
```

Comment: I have made made my whole app in view based so i can't go for navigation based app

Comment: how i can change my view based application into navigation based.is in't hussel for me

Comment: Usually when people want left-right animation like this they are kind of emulating navigation. If so, it really isn't that hard to switch.

Comment: See my edit to make your View based app into a navigation based

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)slideView:(UIView*)view direction:(BOOL)isLeftToRight {
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = (isLeftToRight) ? -320 : 320;
    view.frame = frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I guess it's a good approach if you want to implement "custom modalTransition"

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you should do this through Navigational Controller.**

Here is some code to help you, if you want to do it through Navigational Controller.

In AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>{

    UINavigationController *navController;
}
```

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // ViewController is your FirstViewController which loads over Window.

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = _viewController;
    navController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Then in your ViewController.m, in your button tapped function, you can do this:

```
NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

And that's all.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[self.navigatationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```